# Count / Sum cell values based on background / font color

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a range contains different contents with different colors.
I want to count the cells with the same font color in it.
how can I do ?
regards

Comment: well that depends, are the colors due to conditional formatting?

Comment: Yeah it can consists, if I prefer use conditional formatting ,could u please write it how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some Visual Basic code that accomplishes this task. Found it on [this site.](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1418-excel-count-sum-by-font-color.html)

```
Public Function CountColour(pRange1 As Range, pRange2 As Range) As Double
Application.Volatile
Dim rng As Range
For Each rng In pRange1
    If rng.Font.Color = pRange2.Font.Color Then
        CountColour = CountColour + 1
    End If
Next
End Function
```

To create the CountColour function, press **ALT-F11**, then **Insert->Module**, and write the above function in that window and save it. To use the function, use this syntax on the cell where you want your data displayed: =CountColour(XX:YY,ZZ) where XX:YY represents the cell range you want to count, and ZZ being a cell whose colour you want to count in the given range.